# Will this setup allow me to grow a large jungle tree in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve been trying to grow a large jungle tree in a specific area, but the problem is nothing seems to be growing, and I’m not sure if the reason is how close it is to the walls or whatever the problem is.

Should this setup hail results, and if not, what can I do to fix it? How much space do I need on the side of the tree for it to grow?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree):

In order to grow a 2×2 tree (be it spruce, jungle or dark oak), four saplings must be placed adjacent to each other in a square. For growth to succeed, there must be **no blocks adjacent** (even diagonally) **to the north-western side** up to the final height of the tree.

[image]

> This jungle tree cannot grow because of the red wool block (looking from the northwestern corner)

And this looks like your case.
If you really want that wall so close to the tree, remove the wall and make the tree grow, then rebuild it in the same position.